# Haskell minimum/maximum Double Constant

Tags: haskell, floating-point, constants

Is there any way in Haskell to get the constant that is the largest and smallest possible positive rational number greater than zero that can be represented by doubles?

Comment: Truly, looking back, I have no idea why I wanted to know this ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
maxNonInfiniteFloat :: RealFloat a => a -> a
maxNonInfiniteFloat a = encodeFloat m n where
    b = floatRadix a
    e = floatDigits a
    (_, e') = floatRange a
    m = b ^ e - 1
    n = e' - e

minPositiveFloat :: RealFloat a => a -> a
minPositiveFloat a = encodeFloat 1 $ fst (floatRange a) - floatDigits a
```

Answer (score 1):

[GHC.Float](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/3.0.3.0/doc/html/GHC-Float.html) has the function `[floatRange][2]`:

> floatRange :: a -> (Int, Int)  Source
>
> a constant function, returning the lowest and highest values the exponent may assume

which should be what you want.

Comment: Umm?  `Prelude.floatRange` works on all instances of `class RealFloat`, including `Double`.